# Sharepoint Restore on Production environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, sharepoint-server

I have this scenario. I am not sure how to implement it. I am using Sharepoint 2010. I have a site on client environment and it has the production data. Now I have made some changes to the sharepoint site on my development server. These changes include columns in list and libraries, views on list and libraries, some new lists and libraries Top navigation added etc... Here my problem is to make this change available in the production environment. If I restore the backup to the production environment then all the production data are gone and it has to be added fresh. Is there a way to update the site(not manually making the changes) at the production environment without restoring it ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export the new lists as templates and add them to prod.

For existing lists - add columns manually or use some kind of migration tool (e.g. ShareGate - handles well changes in list structure, also newly create items).

Or you can user powershell and script changes - use this approach in the future and you can modify with one script dev and prod as well (if you have necessary permissions and access to powershell on prod).

Comment: I do have access to powershell. can we make the site changes using powershell script?

Comment: Sure, just check the technet gallery how to add a new field to SharePoint list. There is a nice function which is super easy to call to create a field. Should help you a lot. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-add-a-new-field-to-52b0c95f

Comment: I think this should do. That was more helpful. Thanks.